# Why can't I have multiple application instances from the GUI?

Tags: window, putty

I have locked my Putty application to the sidebar so that when I click on it, it launches Putty. So lets say I then use it to ssh to a router, it will then launch a shell to that router. Now let's say I want to use Putty to ssh to another router. I try and click/use another instance of Putty using the sidebar GUI button of Putty, but nothing happens. I believe it's because it thinks the application is open in another window. But when I used Windows 7, I would just right click the application and click launch putty, which would bring up another instance of putty I could use to connect to another router. How can I mimic this same functionality in Ubuntu from the sidebar GUI button?  Currently, I have to open up a new terminal & launch Putty from there in order to get another instance open, which makes my windows very clunky if I need to open 10 or 20 sessions to various network devices seen as I need 1 window to execute putty, and another window when putty ssh's to a network device. Seems silly to use twice as many windows as required.

Comment: Is it really important for you  to use putty? you can ssh another device straight from the terminal. If you don't mind using the terminal to ssh I can write an answer to your question.

Comment: Ok sure. I will use the terminal.

Comment: Ok ill post the answer

Comment: I have posted my answer, please tell me if I have to edit anything in case it is not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use the normal terminal to ssh instead.

To launch the terminal use use the keyboard shortcut(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) or you can search for `terminal` from the dash.

To ssh another machine, you can the command

```
ssh user@hostname
```

The hostname can be the ip address of the router or the domain name if it has one.

Once you open a terminal and ssh to another machine it does not open another window.

Answer (score 0):

You can run 2 instances of `PuTTY` if you run it from the terminal, as so:

```
putty &
```

I'm hoping there is a better answer, like not having to use the terminal but this is what I have found so far.